# How to set string.xml in mainactivity?

Tags: android, android-studio

how to set strings in mainactivity.java

i want somethig like this

> url: www.example.com/?lang=1
>   if(lang=1){ here select
>   values/strings.xml }else{ in else i want to select  hi/strings.xml }

**values/strings.xml**

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name" translatable="false">LOGO KiNG</string>
    <string name="app_menu1">Home</string>
    <string name="app_menu2">About</string>
    <string name="app_menu3">Test</string>
    <string name="app_menu4">Term</string>
    <string name="app_menu5">Setting</string>

</resources>
```

**hi/strings.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Vidhyapeeth PORT</string>
    <string name="app_menu1">होम</string>
    <string name="app_menu2">अबाउट</string>
    <string name="app_menu3">टेस्ट</string>
    <string name="app_menu4">टर्म</string>
    <string name="app_menu5">सेटिंग</string>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

Select your Hindi string in your main activity you need to set Locale

Do like as below

Create a class
public

```
class LocaleHelper {
private static final String SELECTED_LANGUAGE = "Locale.Helper.Selected.Language";

public static void onCreate(Context context) {
    setLocale(context, getPersistedData(context, Locale.getDefault().getLanguage()));
}

public static void onCreate(Context context, String defaultLanguage) {
    setLocale(context, getPersistedData(context, defaultLanguage));
}

public static String getLanguage(Context context) {
    return getPersistedData(context, Locale.getDefault().getLanguage());
}

public static void setLocale(Context context, String language) {
    persist(context, language);
    updateResources(context, language);
}

private static String getPersistedData(Context context, String defaultLanguage) {
    return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).getString(SELECTED_LANGUAGE, defaultLanguage);
}

private static void persist(Context context, String language) {
    Editor editor = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).edit();
    editor.putString(SELECTED_LANGUAGE, language);
    editor.apply();
}

private static void updateResources(Context context, String language) {
    Locale locale = new Locale(language);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Resources resources = context.getResources();
    Configuration configuration = resources.getConfiguration();
    configuration.locale = locale;
    resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, resources.getDisplayMetrics());
}
}
```

call this class in your activity like as below and it will change the locale for your full app

```
LocaleHelper.setLocale(this, "hi");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this:

```
<resources>
   <string name="app_name" translatable="false">LOGO KiNG</string>
   <string name="app_menu1">Home</string>
   <string name="app_menu2">About</string>
   <string name="app_name_hi">Vidhyapeeth PORT</string>
   <string name="app_menu1_hi">होम</string>
   <string name="app_menu2_hi">अबाउट</string>

</resources>
```

and use:

```
url: www.example.com/?lang=1
if(lang=1){ context.getString(R.string.app_menu_1) }else{ R.string.app_menu_1_hi }
```